# How do I filter out an error spamming in adb logcat in command prompt?

Tags: adb, command-prompt, logcat, findstr

When I test my VR video playing app, there is always an error spamming when I play a video:

```
OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_ENUM: enum argument out of range
```

I can't find anything to fix this error but it does not affect how my app works. However, when I try to debug something, this error keeps spamming and it's hard for me to look at other messages when this happens. I tried to do some research and found that `findstr /v` may be able to filter out things. So I tried to do these:

```
adb logcat -s Unity | findstr /v OPENGL
```

or

```
adb logcat -s Unity | findstr /v /c:"OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_ENUM: enum argument out of range"
```

Both seem not able to remove the specific error lines. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
adb logcat -s Unity | findstr /r/c:"Unity   : [^ ]" | find /v "OPENGL" | find /v "GfxDeviceGLES.cpp"
```

`findstr /v` did not work so well with logcat so instead of filtering out using `/v`, we use /r to get lines that are not blank, and then filter out those error lines with `find /v`.